# How to add formula on Crystal report fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Below is my crystal report ,I want to perform Formula something like below ,as I am new to crystal report how can I do this ?

```
if (`Fee_unit`==Percent)
{
FeeTotal = (`Fee` divided by 100) * `Number of patients`;
}
else
{
FeeTotal = `Fee` *  `Number of patients`;
}
```

[image: Crystal report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Field Explorer -> Formula-> New Formula.

```
From the drop down above select Basic Syntax.

If {TableName.FeeUnit} = {TableName.Percent} Then // Assuming you have FeeUni and Percent as column in TableName table. Drag drop the two and wrap with the code
    formula=({TableName.Fee}/100)*{TableName.Patients}  // formula here is a keyword

Else 
    formula={TableName.Fee}*{TableName.Patients}  
End If
```

Comment: Fee_Unit is Table name ,But Percent is its value so how do i do this